# ReactJS: Relationship between Components (Dependency)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have two Components: `Table` (parent: `Tables`) and `Connection` (parent: `Connections`). The parent of `Tables` and `Connections` is `App`.
The problem is that Table needs to be rendered before Connection is rendered. The Connection Component creates a connection (with a line) between two Table components, so what I do is that I'm read the position of the `Table` components (with jQuery) and create the connection. But at the time of rendering the connection the `Table` components aren't rendered yet.

What can I do about that? Is there a better approach? Or can I define dependencies?

UPDATE:

Actually it's a connection between two `Column` components, but they are part of the `Table` component which can be moved with drag'n'drop. So the solution also should provide the possibility to update/refresh the connections.

Example Coding:

`Table` component

```
class Table extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
    this.dragMoveListener = this.dragMoveListener.bind(this);
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount(){
  // ...
}

dragMoveListener(event) {
  // will be called after with drag'n'drop, so there is a refresh neccessary
  this.setState({x: this.state.x + event.dx, y: this.state.y + event.dy });
}

style() {
  return {
    transform: 'translate(' + this.state.x + 'px, ' + this.state.y + 'px)'
  };
}

render() {

  var self = this;

  var ncolumns = this.props.table.columns.map(function(c,i) {
    return <Column key={i} tablename={self.props.table.name} column={c} tindex={self.props.index} cindex={i}></Column>;
  });

  return (<div style={this.style()} className="table draggable">
            <div id={this.props.table.name} className="entry table-name">{this.props.table.name}</div>
            {ncolumns}
         </div>);
}
}
```

`Connection` component:

```
class Connection extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    style(thickness,length,cx,cy,angle) {
        return {
            padding: '0px',
            margin: '0px',
            height: thickness + 'px',
            backgroundColor: '#eee',
            lineHeight: '1px',
            position: 'absolute',
            left: cx + 'px',
            top: cy + 'px',
            width: length + 'px',
            transform: 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
        }
    }
    render() {
            var a = $('#'+this.props.connection.table_a + '-' + this.props.connection.column_a);
            var b = $('#'+this.props.connection.table_b + '-' + this.props.connection.column_b);
            // some math to get length, angle between tables/columns etc.
        return(<div style={this.style(thickness,length,cx,cy,angle)} />);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post of sample of your code? But I think if you're not already, check out the componentDidMount() lifecyle method. You can run functions and trigger changes when your component is mounted on the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `<App>` create a callback function `tablesDidRender()` which will call `setState({tablesDidRender: true})` (in `App`). Pass that function to the `<Tables>` component and call it in `componentDidMount` (the life cycle method called after the first render). 
In your `<App>` you can now render `<Connections>` based on `this.state.tablesDidRender`:

- If `true`: render `<Connections>`
- If `false`: render nothing (`null`)

Comment: For the first rendering it seems to work. But what I worry about is how to refresh the connections after first rendering. Do you have an idea for that? The componentDidMount function seems to be called only once, so it doesn't help me to set tablesDidRender back to false somewhere. The components can be moved while runtime, so it has often to be refreshed.

Comment: For the moment I got it to work with ``this.forceUpdate()`` in ``<App>`` what is not really elegant. Maybe you have a better idea.

Comment: There are other life cycle methods too: like `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` or `componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState`
Check here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html